My module installed from GitHub is not being updated after new commits
I've created a python module and posted in on GitHub. The thing is, I've updated it several times and my friends, who installed it via python3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/link-to-repo. When I update the git repo, they update it via python3 -m pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/link-to-repo, but new functionality that I add in new commits does not work for them.
I am not sure where is my module actually installed on their computer, so I can't really see the source code on their machine and can't know the real reason for this behaviour. This also checks in my computer. If I want my module to perform new functionality, I have to pip uninstall it and then install it again.
Thanks in advance for your help, I am willing to share additional info on my project.
After pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/link-to-project I expect it to perform new functionality when called from terminal. Instead, it seems like it is not updated.

If the version is not updated, it probably wont reinstall, try adding the --force-reinstall flag

Please try these solutions:

Check the installation path: Run python -m pip show your_module_name to verify where the module is installed

Force a clean install: Try pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir git+https://github.com/link-to-repo to bypass any cached versions

If none of that works, you can try an editable installation: Use pip install -e git+https://github.com/link-to-repo#egg=your_module_name to install your module in "editable" mode, so changes reflect immediately (see: When would the -e, --editable option be useful with pip install?)



you can also use --force-reinstall flag

Thanks! The no-cache-dir did the work.
Also, @TomMcLean 's solution to pass --force-reinstall is also working
